# Are SSTO (Single Stage To Orbit) vehicles cost effective?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've been experimenting with building rockets that can make it into orbit with a single stage, decouple and then land/splash the booster section with a probe core in control (or sometimes Jeb in a command chair).

They work rather well and I can get about half of the booster cost back but I find that my expendable asparagus booster designs are still cheaper to deliver the same payload to orbit.

Is there some payload amount or specific design that makes SSTO boosters more cost effective?

Comment: See http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/117025-The-Race-to-Publish-the-First-KSP-1-0-Compatible-Spaceplane-SSTO for some info on version 1 attempts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're keeping *all* of the booster parts intact, then the cost efficiency depends largely on how close you can land your booster to KSC. That's going to depend more on your skills at re-entry and landing than anything else.

There's another cost involved: the cost of the extra fuel you'll burn from getting a larger/heavier launch vehicle to orbit. However, fuel is pretty cheap; the cost to fill the [largest tank in the stock game](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Kerbodyne_S3-14400_Tank) is about 6600 Kerbal Funds; that's only somewhat more than a [single Mainsail engine](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Rockomax_%22Mainsail%22_Liquid_Engine).

If you're able to land your booster close to KSC and recover the majority of your parts costs, you'll likely be able to get better cost efficiency from an SSTO. Incidentally, this is why SSTO spaceplanes are worth doing; they make precise landings much more plausible.

Comment: Whoa, you are saying that the recovery amount is directly related to how close you are to KSC?

Comment: @BiffMaGriff: As of 0.24, yes. You'll see that at the top of the "Parts" section of your [mission debriefing window](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/File:Part_recovery.png). If you can land on the KSC pad or runway, you'll get 100% of the cost of the vehicle's parts back in Funds. That percentages decreases (quite rapidly in fact) the further away you are.

Comment: Since version .25 you can also activate the "Recovery Transponder Fitting" upgrade in the administration building which reduces the penalty for recovering a vehicle far away from the space center. It does however increase your overall part cost, so it is only profitable when you use a lot of SSTO crafts.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer last year. But now with version 1.0 and the new aerodynamic system it seems to be quite outdated. Maybe you would like to revise it? I put a bounty of 50 points on this question.

Comment: @Philipp: I haven't played in a while so I can't comment on v1.0 specifically. However, as long as the closer-recovery-gives-more-funds mechanic is still in place, then the bulk of my answer still applies. The new aerodynamics might change how easy it is to land close to KSC, but they don't affect the principle directly.